# Jquery conflict in Magento broke my add to cart button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

I'm having issues with my add to cart button in the Magento product description page only.  The Grid page still works perfectly.  I have several jquery files added to my XML as vendor dependencies.  When I remove Jquery.Js the button works fine but my slider and lightbox break.  Any clue on how to fix this?  I've read several posts on no conflict but not a clear explanation.

```
<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>jquery-1.11.2.min.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/noconflict.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>bootstrap.min.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>jasny-bootstrap.min.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>jquery-ui.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>datepicker/datepickerScript.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>tabs/tabsScript.js</script></action>

            <block type="page/js_cookie" name="js_cookies" template="page/js/cookie.phtml"/>

            <!-- Remove items which the RWD package is not dependent upon -->
            <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name></action>

            <!-- Add vendor dependencies -->
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/video-lightbox/swfobject.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/modernizr.custom.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/selectivizr.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/matchMedia.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/matchMedia.addListener.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/enquire.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/app.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/jquery.cycle2.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/jquery.cycle2.swipe.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/slideshow.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/imagesloaded.js</name></action>
            <action method="addLinkRel"><rel>stylesheet</rel><href>//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,700,600</href></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/minicart.js</name></action>
```

Comment: try removing jquery 1.11.2.min.js and keep only jquery.js at start

Comment: I tried that already.  No joy.

Comment: then you have to assign the variable to each version of loaded jquery and use the respective version in respective required plugins.

Comment: You mean the no conflict correct?

Comment: yes. <script src=jquery-1.11.2.min.js> var jq1112 = jquery.noConflict() </script> like this way

Comment: That is why I never want to use jQuery in magento project. I once have a situation when magento project I've been assigned to required jQuery 1.7 (as large parts of js was using it for some reason - previous dev left hard checking and throwing exception) and I was asked to add amazon payments module which came with its own jQuery 1.4 that was bundled inside one external js with other script for the module. I spent probably 15 hours trying to resolve it somehow.

Comment: I finally resolved this issue.  What was happening was the previous developer had added third party  plugins (WOW Slider and Lightbox) to the home page.  As such he added Jquery min file to the XML as a vendor dependency.  I ripped all third party plugins out and removed jquery from the vendor dependency on the page.XML.  I then rebuilt the lightbox/modal and slider using bootstrap jquery.  The lightbox/modal needed some additional jquery so I added that to the static block right under the HTML and added no conflict to the script.  Everything worked like a charm now.